# Find Match in Javascript Object and Array using Jquery Each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Trying to use an array of filters to search a javascript object of store locations, and i need to get a full match using both filters from the filters array, which now has 2 items, but will have more. The code below works, but it's finding matches for each store. Since one store in the .json file does not have an ATM machine, it should not come up in the console. Any help would be appreciated!

.json:

```
[
{
    "storenumber": "5210",
    "services": [
        {
            "img": "/locator/img/icons/atm.svg",
            "alt": "ATM Machine"
        },
        {
            "img": "/locator/img/icons/carwash.svg",
            "alt": "Car Wash"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "storenumber": "1066",
    "services": [
        {
            "img": "/locator/img/icons/carwash.svg",
            "alt": "Car Wash"
        }

    ]
}
]
```

.js:

```
var jsonData,
    filteredJsonData = [],
    filters = ["Car Wash","ATM Machine"];

   $.getJSON("/locator/js/locations.json")
    .done(function(data) {
        jsonData = data;

        $.each(jsonData,function(locationsIndex,locationsItem){
            var services = locationsItem.services;

            $.each(services,function(servicesIndex,servicesItem){
                if (servicesItem.alt && ($.inArray(servicesItem.alt,filters) != -1)) {
                    // This is finding matches in the filters array, but i need to match all items in the array
                    console.log("Match Found: " + servicesItem.alt + " at Index " + locationsIndex)
                    filteredJsonData.push(locationsItem)
                }
            })
        })  
        console.log(filteredJsonData)
    })
```

Comment: Should you not consider all filter results and find those that exist for all the filters, before including them in your final result?  It sounds like you are adding them to the final result so long as they pass any single filter.

Comment: Consider using every ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every ), to determine if the element being filtered matches all the filters.

Comment: Why did i get downvoted, i've been researching this question all morning on  the site, and finally broke down and asked for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `filter`, `some` and a `Set`:

```js
const jsonData = [{"storenumber": "5210","services": [{ "img": "/locator/img/icons/atm.svg","alt": "ATM Machine"},{"img": "/locator/img/icons/carwash.svg","alt": "Car Wash"}]}, {"storenumber": "1066","services": [{"img": "/locator/img/icons/carwash.svg","alt": "Car Wash"}]}],
    filters = ["Car Wash","ATM Machine"];

const locations = jsonData.filter( location => {
    const filterSet = new Set(filters);
    return location.services.some( service => {
        filterSet.delete(service.alt);
        return !filterSet.size;
    });
});
console.log(locations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: I removed the Ajax call just for the purpose of this demo snippet.

#### For older browsers

A version that will work in old browsers (ES3, mainly IE), making use of jQuery:

```js
var jsonData = [{"storenumber": "5210","services": [{ "img": "/locator/img/icons/atm.svg","alt": "ATM Machine"},{"img": "/locator/img/icons/carwash.svg","alt": "Car Wash"}]}, {"storenumber": "1066","services": [{"img": "/locator/img/icons/carwash.svg","alt": "Car Wash"}]}],
    filters = ["Car Wash","ATM Machine"];

var locations = $.grep(jsonData, function (location) {
    var filterSet = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        filterSet[filters[i]] = 1;
    }
    var filtersLeft = filters.length;
    $.each(location.services, function (i, service) {
        if (filterSet[service.alt]) {
            filtersLeft--;
            filterSet[service.alt] = 0; 
        };
        return filtersLeft > 0;
    });
    return filtersLeft === 0;
});
console.log(locations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works! Will it function in IE9 though?

Comment: I added a version that will run on old browsers.

Comment: Works! I have been researching this all day with much frustration and this is some solid help. You sir are a legend.